# What are the best practices for database scaling?

Tags: sql, mysql, scalable, database-server

What are the best practices to design a scalable database? If database / tables span on multiple servers, how can I join them?

Where can I get more information for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610887/how-to-partition-mysql-across-multiple-servers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a white-paper on how to scale out mysql

[Scale out mysql](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql_wp_scaleout.php)

Although, IMO, if you are looking to scale a database using multiple servers, you should take a look (use) no-sql databases. Here is a link where you can start your research

[nosql-database org](http://nosql-database.org/)