# Load balanceing for database

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I am going to start working on a huge application.
before that I want to prepare my self for it.

This is a application which will be used world wide, and there will be big number of users using it at same time.

1. So what I think is, there will be big load on one database server, plenty of request/queries on database in narrow time frame. so this will hit system's performance, right?
2. If Database server goes down, It will cost very much to owner of website.

so what should I do? is there any technology or something I can use?
If I can use multiple database, then how? will all database contain same information? can I join tables (using any tech. or tool) between diff. database? or I have to do multiple queries in each for each database?

Application will be with : jboss,jsp,servlet,mysql

Answer (score 0):

It is always best if requirements can be given with some precision. For instance, we expect no more than 1,000 users to be hitting the database simultaneously is a clear design requirement. "There will be a big number of users" is much less helpful. Of course, we can not always predict how much traffic a web application will get and requirements often change over time.

If a database will be experiencing far more reads than writes, then caching data from the database can improve performance. This was the topic of a recent podcast that you might want to listen to: http://javaposse.com/java-posse-399-roundup-12-distributed-caching

Spreading a database among many servers is a complicated task because you need to deal with synchronization issues. Your best bet is to find a service or API that takes care of this issue for you. You can use MySQL, (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610887/how-to-partition-mysql-across-multiple-servers)) but another database designed for this sort of scaling is probably a better choice. Take a look at [hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/).